# Flow rate at the vent exit

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, cfd, fluent

I am working on a vent. The vent is attached to a box and is designed to extract air out of the box using the venturi effect. Air is made to flow over the vent which creates a significant pressure difference between the face of the vent and the inside of the box making air to flow out. I have performed the Analysis using Fluent and trying to figure our the flow rate(mass flow rate) of the air escaping from the vent outlet.

I am new to CFD and want to know how to find that out from my analysis?

[image]Please find attached a photo which shows the setup.

Comment: Make sure that there is a boundary for air to enter your box or there will be no flow. For the software specific questions, you may have a look at https://www.cfd-online.com/ if you don't get any feedback here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't get your point to add a boundary for air to enter the box. My whole setup is to vent the air out of the box and create a vacuum in there. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Ah ok. If you are pulling a vacuum your flowrate will be variable. Largest at startup then taper off as it reaches steady state of zero flow. You either have to solve this transient condition or pick what pressure you wish to know the flowrate at and define your model as such.